# Preventing Users from signing in Microsoft Edge

Tags: group-policy, microsoft-edge

Internet Explorer mode pages in Microsoft Edge  will expires 30 days if there users is signed into Microsoft Edge .

Can I find out is there any GPO to prevent users to sign into edge / use a local Profile so the script https://github.com/LesFerch/SampleCode/blob/main/VBS-misc/IEModeExpiryFix.vbs can be executed successfully.

Comment: [Accounts: Block Microsoft account](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5ebf1330-5504-4eb0-b236-7bfae8f7548f/disable-add-a-microsoft-online-account-via-gpo-windows-10-pro) should be what your looking for.

Comment: If you confirm that GPO blocks linking to a Microsoft Account within Edge, like I think it might, I will submit an answer.

Comment: I will try to test if it can work.

Comment: @Ramhound  Will it affect anything if i were to disable the Block Microsoft account ? will it prevent my users to be able to log in if my ad is tied to Microsoft account ?

Comment: You should test.

Comment: @Ramhoud - Thank you for your help. So far i did not try out the answer you suggested.  I managed to refer to this link to try editing the registry editor and it works https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/162032-how-enable-disable-force-sign-microsoft-edge-chromium.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit through Registry editor.

To Disable Sign in to Microsoft Edge for All Users

A) Click/tap on the Download button below to download the file below, and go to step 5 below.

Disable_sign_in_to_Microsoft_Edge.reg

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/162032-how-enable-disable-force-sign-microsoft-edge-chromium.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).